# 3d view is not properly updating

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I am writing a script to stack three cubes.  I would like the user to be able to change the thickness of each cube independently and then have my code restack them on top of each other.  The problem is that if the user changes the thickness of one of the cubes, the 3d view does not update automatically.
[image]

I have a panel to change the thickness of any of the cubes.  If the user changes the thickness of the top cube, the locations of the cubes are updated in my code, but not automatically in the 3d view.
[image]

If I change the layer number in my panel, then the view updates.  Using bpy.context.view_layer.update() after I update the sizes and locations of the cubes does not help.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me get the cube locations to change automatically.

Here is my code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator,PropertyGroup

chooselayer=[("1","Layer 1","0.014,0.003,0.157,1"),
    ("2","Layer 2","0.014,0.003,0.157,1"),
    ("3","Layer 3","0.014,0.003,0.157,1")]

length = 10
thickness1=10
thickness2=5
thickness3=2

def get_layer_params(self,context):
    layerEnum=bpy.context.scene.layerProps.layerEnum  #which layer
    objlayer=bpy.data.objects["Layer.s"+layerEnum]
    bpy.context.scene.layerProps.thickness=objlayer.dimensions.z

def update_layer(self,context):
    print("in update layer")
    layerlist=[]

    for obj in bpy.data.collections['Collection'].all_objects:
        if "Layer" in obj.name:
            layerlist.append(obj)  
    if layerlist==[]:
        return
    
    layernum=bpy.context.scene.layerProps.layerEnum
    thickness=bpy.context.scene.layerProps.thickness

    changeLayerName="Layer.s"+str(layernum)
    print(changeLayerName, thickness)
    changeobj=bpy.data.objects[changeLayerName]
 
    thicknessTotal=0
    for layerobj in layerlist:
        if layerobj.name==changeLayerName:
            layerobj.dimensions=[length,length,thickness]
        layerobj.location=[0,0,-thicknessTotal-layerobj.dimensions.z]
        layerobj.location.z=-thicknessTotal-layerobj.dimensions.z/2
        thicknessTotal+=layerobj.dimensions.z
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()

class LayerParams(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    layerEnum : EnumProperty(
        items = chooselayer,
        name = "Choose a Layer",
        update = get_layer_params)
    thickness: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="thickness",update=update_layer,default=thickness1)

def setLayers():
    thickness=[thickness1,thickness2,thickness3]
    thicknessTotal=0
 
    for layernum in range(1,len(thickness)+1): #["Layer.s1","Layer.s2"."Layer.s3"]:
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(scale=(length,length,thickness[layernum-1]))
        objlayer=bpy.context.active_object
        objlayer.name="Layer.s"+str(layernum)
        objlayer.location=[0,0,-thicknessTotal-thickness[layernum-1]/2]
        thicknessTotal += thickness[layernum-1]

class SCENE_PT_layer(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Properties Window"""
    bl_label = "Define layer"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layer"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene=context.scene
        layout.use_property_split = True
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene.layerProps, "layerEnum", text="Choose Layer")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene.layerProps, "thickness", text="thickness") 

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SCENE_PT_layer)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayerParams)
    bpy.types.Scene.layerProps=bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=LayerParams)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayerParams)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SCENE_PT_layer)
    del bpy.types.Scene.layerProps
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    setLayers()
```

Comment: I just started your code and it works. It updates the 3D view. Maybe you should restart Blender and run your script from scratch again.

Comment: I have been struggling with the problem for quite a while.  I just did as you suggested, I even disabled the Addon that I am working on, loaded factory settings from the file menu, and it still does not update automatically.  I am using Blender 2.92.  Is there possibly a setting that I need to change?  I don't see anything obvious in the user preferences.

Comment: Ok, I try with 2.92

Comment: works with 2.92 here. Do you have the newest 2.92?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a bug on your version. You might consider dropping it at developer.blender.org so it can be fixed.

Comment: Is there a chance you're just missing bmesh.update_edit_mesh([mesh]) before bpy.context.view_layer.update()? This sounds a lot like an issue with BMesh's data duality not getting synchronized at the right time. It would also explain why it works on some systems but not others.

Comment: I added            me=layerobj.data
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)  to the for loop where I update the location of the cubes in update_layer.  I am not certain I did that correctly, but it did not help.  As far as I can tell, Blender 2.92 was released at the end of February and I updated to 2.92 in March.  I thought that I had gotten this working, so perhaps it stopped working when I updated my Blender version.  I will try developer.blender.org.